# How can I generate the Abstract Syntax Tree for a CoffeeScript File?

Tags: coffeescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I realize that CoffeeScript compiles to JavaScript. But is it possible to generate an AST for CoffeeScript without having to convert it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source for the nodes created by the CoffeeScript compiler [here](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/nodes.html).

It's been a while since I investigated the best way to do this but when I wrote [CoffeeDocTest](https://github.com/lmaccherone/coffeedoctest), I used the [CoffeeDoc wrapper of the CoffeeScript parser](https://github.com/omarkhan/coffeedoc/blob/master/src/parsers.coffee).